# Ruby on Rails Devise Custom Form-- Form not Updating on Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, erb

I am using Rails 4, Ruby 2.2, and the latest version of the 'Devise' gem.

So far, I have generated a devise User resource, and created a migration with custom fields (firstName, lastName, etc). This worked fine.

I created a strong parameter on my applications controller, seen here:

```
      before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

      protected

      def configure_permitted_parameters
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :password, :email, :firstName, :lastName, :dateofBirth, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip)}
      end
```

I proceeded to create a view for the User resource with the devise command on my terminal. I checked my routes via rake to ensure that I am loading "new.html.erb" file upon the URL "/users/sign_up".

The issue I am having is when I go to update my sign up form on new, it doesn't update! I have changed the code to include other fields, but it still shows the same standard form that comes with devise (email, password, password confirmation), even though in the erb file that is linked through the route i have explicitly added three more fields for username and first name and last name.

I have tried editing the header and even that doesn't update! When I update other view files, they update fine, so it is not an overall view issue.

This is my code for the "new.html.erb":

```
     <h2>Sign up</h2>
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

 <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :username %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true %>
        </div>
     <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firstName %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :firstName %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
   <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

I am speculating the devise gem may be overriding the user specific view and sending a default view (which would explain no updating), but am not sure how to solve this issue if this is indeed the issue.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you explain this ***The issue I am having is when I go to update my sign up form on new, it doesn't update!***?

Comment: I have changed the code to include other fields, but it still shows the same standard form that comes with devise (email, password, password confirmation), even though in the erb file that is linked through the route i have explicitly added three more fields for username and first name and last name. @Pavan

Comment: I'm confused. Are using the `new.html.erb` for update action too?

Comment: this is just for the account sign up. i have a separate view for update. going to check if that form is editable or not. when i typed "update my sign up form" i meant changing the composition of the form, as in adding extra elements. thanks. @Pavan

Comment: i changed something in the configuration and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i changed a scope setting in the initializer, restarted the webricks server, and it started working